# Navigation won't display inline?

Tags: html, css

Pretty frustrating when something as simple as this has me stuck! I've tried many different things, but for some reason, it's stuck in the vertical display.

Relevant HTML

```css
    body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 90%;
    min-width: 45%;
    background-color: #dadada;
    height: 100%;
    }

    header {
    background-color: black;
    max-width: 90%;
    min-width: 45%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
    font-family: typographica;
    padding: 45px;
    
    }

    .logo h1 {
    text-align: center;
    
    
    }

    h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 300%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    }


    ul li a {
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    
    }

    .nav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
    
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <link href="../Style Docs/Home-page.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >

    </head>

    <body>

    <header>
   
    <div type="logo">
       <h1>Name</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div type="head-wrap">
        <ul type="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   

    <div id="decoration-banner">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    </header>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Like I said, I've tried a lot of different things, but I must be missing something. I'm not sure if it's because of the way I wrote my html or what, but I haven't had this problem before..

Comment: .head-wrap li {display:inline-block}

Comment: Your css is alright, just replace `type` with `class`

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CSS` is looking for a class called `.nav`. If you look at your `<ul>`, you meant to use the attribute `class` but instead used `type`.

```html
<ul type="nav">

</ul>
```

Should be

```html
<ul class="nav">

</ul>
```

Comment: Yep, worked like a charm. I feel silly! Thanks for the fix :)

Comment: @Ewubbs Glad I could help. If you’re happy with my answer, I’d be grateful if you could select it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you're calling a `.nav li`. If you call with a dot, you call a class in CSS.
Just renamed `type` by `class` and it works now.

```css
body {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 90%;
min-width: 45%;
background-color: #dadada;
height: 100%;
}

header {
background-color: black;
max-width: 90%;
min-width: 45%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 1%;
font-family: typographica;
padding: 45px;

}

.logo h1 {
text-align: center;


}

h1 {
color: white;
font-size: 300%;
margin-left: 3%;
position: absolute;
top: 2%;
}


ul li a {
color: white !important;
text-decoration: none;
width: 50%;
position: relative;

}

.nav li {
float: none;
display: inline;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<link href="../Style Docs/Home-page.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >

</head>

<body>

<header>

<div type="logo">
   <h1>Name</h1>
</div>

<div type="head-wrap">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="decoration-banner">
    &nbsp;
</div>
</header>







</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of these two possible ways of doing it:

**1. change it into a table**

```
<table style="width:50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">Discover</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">Upload</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">More</a>
    </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

**2. Use flex and flex-direction**

```
<div type="head-wrap" >
    <ul type="nav" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```